# how to compare two column from same file?

Tags: shell, awk

I have long data file, file.txt

```
1 3  
3 2  
2 3  
5 5  
8 9
```

so out file should be, out.txt

```
1 3  
1 2  
1 5   
1 9  
3 3  
3 2  
3 5
```

Comment: Please post your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Also please explain how to get your expected output in your post.

Comment: I want every possible combination of each element of first column with each element of second should print in new file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$2
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print $1,a[i]
  }
}
' Input_file Input_file
```